# Replacing column strings with numbers in a plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Is there any way to specify column number as an index to show on x-axis? Consider the following dataframe

```
      Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value
0             3            3            7            7
1             1            1            1            1
2             0            0            0            0
```

The code below, plots row[0] however, as you can see, "metric Value" is written on the x points. I would like to see 1, 2, 3, 4 instead.

```
    row = df.iloc[0]
    row.astype(int).plot()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.columns = range(1, len(df.columns)+1)
row = df.iloc[0]
row.astype(int).plot()
plt.show()
```